# Passing variable via post/get to another file using JQuery/Ajax with changing mouse coordinates

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am having index.php which will listens mouse coordinates on moving it. I want to send these coordinates to second file  (say second.php). For this I have placed post fields inside mousemoving activity. But i am unable to receive these values in second.php file. Help me with this thing. I am attaching my code below :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
   $(document).mousemove(function(e)
   {
      $('#status').html(e.pageX);
      $('#status1').html(e.pageY);

        $.post("second.php",
        {
            x:10,
            y:20
        }, function coord(data)
        {   
            $("#div1").load("second.php");  },"html"

        }


   }); 



})

</script>
<body>

<h2 id='status'>
</h2>

<h2 id="status1">
</h2>
<div id="div1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the second file normally receives post values and returns it after addition. Am i going on a wrong track or is there an alternate way for doing this. Help me with it.

Comment: That's a horrible, horrible idea. Everytime the mouse moves one pixel you're sending an ajax request!

Comment: Actually, you're sending two ajax requests.

Comment: You have syntax problem; use `)` instead `}` after `"html"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to not do this thing, every time you move the mouse you send a request is very hard to manage think another way to do what you want.
but this code can works for your scope:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
   $(document).mousemove(function(e)
   {
      $('#status').html(e.pageX);
      $('#status1').html(e.pageY);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'second.php',
        data: { 
            'x': '10', 
            'y': '20' 
        },
        success: function(msg){
            //what you want after request
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to manage for you cause of quick value changes, although you can send your data using below code, but I think it will be better to read data from 'second.php' on certain intervals.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: 'second.php/Your_function_name',
            data: { 'x': anything , 'y': anything},       
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(r) { 
            alert(r.d); // returned value                         
            }
        });
```

If you decided to read data from second file, make a method in first file that returns an array of your values, then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
GetMousePosition();
}
function GetMousePosition()
{
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                url: 'first.php/GET_MOUSE_VALUES',     
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(r) { 
                MousePositionChanged(r.d[0] , r.d[1]);
                }
            });
     setTimeout(function {GetMousePosition();} , 1000);//Get Values every one second
}
```

**EDIT:** In second solution you may lose some values, that can be managed easily by creating an array that saves last (maybe) 5 mouse positions. finally sending the array. That's All